# How to convert Spire.Xls workbook to DataTable for run to my excel cell's value replacement under a certain column

Tags: c#, dataview, spire.xls

I want to build that on excel file cell's value replacement under a certain column app but I get an error

I searched but I could not find any solution

```
using Spire.Xls;
using System;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;


namespace ExcelReplacement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile(@"exa.xls", ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];


            try
            {
                DataView DV = new DataView(workbook);
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("\"Sector Responsible\"ZPLNTMTLG__ZSEKTORSR: ZSEKTORSR LIKE '%{0}%'");

                //Finding
                CellRange range = worksheet.FindString("Example", false, false);

                //Changing
                worksheet.Replace(range.Value, "Result");
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("There is no such a word");

            }


            workbook.SaveToFile("last.xls", ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(workbook.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Spire.Xls.Workbook' to
>   'System.Data.DataTable'   ExcelReplacement    D:\users\26044809\onedrive -
>   arçelik a.ş\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ExcelReplacement\ExcelReplacement\Program.cs    23  Active

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to replace data within a specific column in Excel? If so, use:

```
//Replace data within the 1st column
CellRange range = worksheet.Columns[0].FindString("Example", false, false);
```

For converting worksheet to datatable, use:

```
DataTable datatable = worksheet.ExportDataTable();
```

Comment: worked for me but in some cases was giving formulas instead of values